# Espresso Unit Tests fail on AWS Device Farm but Run locally

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-espresso, android-testing, aws-device-farm

I have an `Espresso` unit test which runs fine locally on my machine. This test is using `ActivityTestRule` and have bunch of dependencies mocked and supplied via [Koin](http://insert-koin.io/). Dependency injection is done in `@Before` method.

Test passes successfully without any issue on my local devices and emulators. Same test fails on `AWS Device Farm`. It tries to initialize my `FirebaseMessagingService` which isn't even part of the test. I am trying to create a manual run there. I have verified that I am uploading correct original `debug` APK and `androidTest` APK. I have also tried `Test Filter` on Device Farm for running specific test class. It executes `@Before` and `@After` but fails during original test because its not able to find some dependency in that Firebase service which is strange because that class has no role in test.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase SDK auto initialize itself though content provider (hack). Firebase SDK requires google play services installed which are missing on amazons fork of android. Your code should be ready to handle missing play services (in general) especially when you plan to run on amazon devices.

For example, follow `Prevent auto initialization` step from tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#prevent-auto-init

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

Later reinit FCM from code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled = true
```

Comment: This code is not being run on Amazon devices but usual Android devices like Google Pixel. I am trying to Run unit tests and it shouldn't even start my regular application class which might be responsible for initializing these Firebase stuff.

Comment: JVM unit tests are not running on android device, but instead on your host machine. I think you are mixing these 2. If it's android test -> runs on android device, creates application from manifest always. If it's jvm unit test -> runs on host machine, doesn't initialize anything over test constructor.

Comment: Yeah, terminology is somewhat confusing. I am not doing JVM unit testing, but, UI unit testing with espresso. There are two kind of tests that you can do for UI, integration and unit testing. In unit testing(UI) we isolate the screen and mock network and any other dependencies. For our UI tests we have written a custom runner which creates the `Application` for us.

Comment: I see, without seeing whole picture I can only suggest to put breakpoint on `FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate` and debug if it's executed during your test run.  If it's not, then firebase initialization is not a problem indeed.